# How can I change the image of an ImageView?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have just started learning android. And i don't know How can I change the image of an `ImageView`? ie it has some Image which was set in the layout but i want to change that image through coding how should i do it ?

Here is the xml file

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#cc8181"
 >

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/image"
  android:layout_width="50dip"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:src="@drawable/icon"
  android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
  android:scaleType="center"/>
```

thanks for replying.

Comment: can you pls be more clear , in your question, i think you may want to display images in imageView dynamically,For Example, when i touch and swipe the next image must be displayed, am i right?

Answer (score 301, accepted):

If you created imageview using xml file then follow the steps.

Solution 1:

Step 1: Create an XML file

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#cc8181"
  >

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/image"
      android:layout_width="50dip"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:src="@drawable/icon"
      android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
      android:scaleType="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Step 2: create an Activity

```
ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
```

Solution 2:

If you created imageview from Java Class

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
```

Answer (score 48):

Have a look at the [ImageView API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html). There are several `setImage*` methods. Which one to use depends on the image you provide. If you have the image as resource (e.g. file res/drawable/my_image.png)

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);  // or (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
```

Comment: can i change the color of the screen through Image view this i have done

Comment: you're linking to the API docs on your pc  :)

Comment: Uups - fixed link. Thanks for information!

Comment: @Uttam: I hope you had used a Layout, set the background color to the Layout, which will appers on your screen

Comment: what should be the value for the silver color does any body know

Comment: Do not use comments to ask questions - nobody will find them and you can not accept the correct answer.

Answer (score 17):

Just to go a little bit further in the matter, you can also set a bitmap directly, like this:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);  
Bitmap bImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.my_image);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bImage);
```

Of course, this technique is only useful if you need to change the image.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            storeViewHolder.storeNameTextView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(array[position], context.getTheme()));
} else {
            storeViewHolder.storeNameTextView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(array[position]));
}
```