# Difference between Simple Widget and Support v4/v7 Widget

Tags: android, android-support-library, support-v4

I am bit confused about the concept , of `v4 and v7 support libraries` , what is difference between them,

And if something is working as simple Widget , why we need v4 / v7 to use it.

> If we are using ActionBar know as now Toolbar , then what is
>   difference between v4-Toolbar or v7-Toolbar , is v7-Toolbar , and how
>   much device/ android versions compatibility lies between either of
>   them

**Edit:**

Sometimes people tend to use check to see if given function is available in `specific SDK/version of Android` why is that , if lower version of android support specific function , and it make sense that same function will and should work for higher versions of android

Comment: 'specific SDK/version' we check if that Device OS API contains the method, for example 'view.setElevation' was introduced in API21, so you have to check if the device is running Android API 21 before calling otherwise it will throw method not found exception if you call it without the check and on pre-21

Comment: it make sense to check older method but sometimes people do checks to run methods that belongs to api level 1 , does it make sense ?

Comment: android is always backward compatible, you don't check older methods, you check the newer only

Comment: check this answer , why he doesn't use else part only [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38854983/5896744)

Comment: where is the answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38854983/5896744

Comment: because `            storeViewHolder.storeNameTextView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(array[position]));
` is deprecated on API 21+