# How do I use an image that i captured using the camera and set that to an ImageView?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am using the following code to capture the image from the camera and store it in the public directory pictures. How do I use the same image and set it as in ImageView?

```
public void take_photo(){
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Contact_info.this,Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},40);
        }
        return;
    }
    Intent cameraIntent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Contact_info.this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},50);
        }
        return;
    }
    File pictureDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    String pictureName = "Image1.jpg";
    File imageFile = new File(pictureDirectory, pictureName);
    Uri pictureUri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        pictureUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", imageFile);

    } else{
        pictureUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    }
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, pictureUri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}
```

My on activity result code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST){
             //Commented since upon using this and trying to save the image in the file, the app crashes giving a null pointer exception
            //Bitmap cameraImage =(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            //contact_image.setImageBitmap(cameraImage);
        }
    }
}
```

I do not want to know how to set the image in an ImageView, I want to know how i can use the image that is taken by the camera and stored in the phone directory as the image in the ImageView

Comment: in onactivityresult  u get a data obj from that you can get uri and set it to ur desired imageview

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity

You also have a lot of support on the official Android developer's website:
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the image of an ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089300/how-can-i-change-the-image-of-an-imageview)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void takePicture() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
    }

    private static File getOutputMediaFile(){
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CameraDemo");

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }
```

set image from the mcapturedUri obtained from above method, I hope you are handling the permissions & results part

Answer (score 0):

try this in your on activity for result

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }  
}
```

Comment: The app crashes giving a NullPointerException:Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference

Comment: please paste your onactivity for result

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full working code:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File f = Utils.createImageFile(getContext());
        chooserIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        photoURI = Uri.fromFile(f);
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_PHOTO_CAMERA);


    }

    private void checkCameraPermission() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                            .setMessage(getString(R.string.camera_request_cancelled))
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.dismiss, null)
                            .setOnDismissListener(dialog -> requestPermissions(
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA))
                            .show();
                } else {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
                }
            } else {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        } else {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        /*if (requestCode == REQUEST_PHOTO_CAMERA && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            receiptImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            savePhoto(imageBitmap);

        }
*/
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PHOTO_CAMERA && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (photoURI != null) {
                Uri selectedImage = photoURI;
                getActivity().getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                Bitmap reducedSizeBitmap = Utils.getBitmap(photoURI.getPath());
                if (reducedSizeBitmap != null) {
                    receiptImage.setImageBitmap(reducedSizeBitmap);
                    savePhoto(reducedSizeBitmap);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error while capturing Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error while capturing Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void savePhoto(Bitmap bitmap) {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        File file = null;
        try {
            file = File.createTempFile("photo", null, getContext().getCacheDir());
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
            photoURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        uploadImage(file);
    }
```